# Is there a statistical law that can determine quantity of experiment and predict accuracy of results in my experimental context?

Tags: cross-validation, sampling

I designed a biological protocol A which measures a continuous variable qA for each sample

I designed a biological  protocol B which measures a continuous variable qB for each same sample as above

Since the protocol B is much faster than the protocol A, I want to replace protocol A with protocol B.

In the next future, I will make **n** measures with protocol A and protocol B , and will learn to predict qA from qB. (we suspect qA and qB are linearly dependant)

My question is : Is there a stasticical law that I can apply to estimate in advance how many measures (**n**) I have to do to obtain a given accuracy when predicting qA from qB ?

I am not a statistician, so I am not sure if my question is well explained. I can explain more or add more hypothesis if needed.

Comment: Large sample theory can help you. Sample size derminnation is possible. Linear-dependance can be checked  by implementing a postulated linear model.

Comment: Welcome to cross validated. I think your answer has a chance to get more specific answers if you explain a bit more about the task/application (if you say, "It's E coli strain identification") and the data A and B generate ("A generates one variate per measured sample, B has 500 variates").

Answer (score 2):

I'm speaking from the perspective of an analytical chemist/chemometrician here.

As it is, the question is extremely general, and this means the answers will be very general and probably worst-case as well (since we don't have sufficient information about your study to tell you that in this particular case, things are easier, because...)

So here goes:

- For a regression model, sample size (=number) planning can be done only after preliminary experiments.
  (Sometimes you can start with guesstimates from very similar situations, but that requires a lot of expertise/experience in the application, data generation process and statistics at the same time)
- The complexity of the model and sample size depend on each other: more complex models need far larger sample size. Larger sample size allows more complex models. The more complex model may allow a better prediction of qA - but you'll be able to test this only when you actually have a sufficiently large sample size (and all this already within linear models!).

  This means that it can be very hard in practice to predict the learning curve (predictive performance as function of the training sample size) for the practical purpose of sample size planning.

  OTOH, it is often possible to calculate a minimum sample size for internal verification (often called "validation"). When a continuous qA is predicted (regression) this still needs some preliminary experiments, but then it is far more straightforward than for predicting the required training sample size.

  For "easy" relationships, this "verification sample size" can be the actual bottleneck.
- There are sequential strategies that add (batches of) new samples as long as needed, and with the characteristics that turn out to be most needed. In general, unless you have a very good idea about the system under study beforehand, it is often a good idea to approach the development of such a predictive model in a statistical design with several rounds.

All in all, I'd probably approach this by

1. preliminary experiment with small but not unreasonably small sample size
2. from that calculate what uncertainty you have on your internal verification (e.g. by cross validation of your model) and how precise the verification results need to be for practical purposes.
3. model with 1 + 2, see how good you are, and decide how many more samples you obtain in the next batch.
   Rinse and repeat.

Such a sequential strategy can also help to adjust the experimental design in case some influencing factors become known only on the way.